# Como llenar un formulario con lo que ya tiene para editarlo con Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

CONTEXTO:

Soy pasante con menos de un mes codando y prácticamente estoy sin senior por la pandemia, pues todas las reuinones con zoom son de 1 hora.

Mis conocimientos escasos son basados rails para backend y por eso fui contratado. La cuestión es que se ha tenido cambios, y por ello ahora estoy con vue.

En el trabajo me dijeron que me basara en la view de otro compañero que supuestamente era parecida, la cuestión es que el maneja poca información y yo manejo mucho más, por lo que decidieron cambiarla.

AL CASO:

Cuando tengo que crear un producto, se abre un modal. Ahora para editar, se quiere el mismo modal pero con las informaciones precargadas.

El código de mi compañero que edita TODA la tabla es el siguiente:

```js
<form>
        <table class="table table-borderless rounded">
          
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(product, index) in products" :key="index">

               <td v-if="index==updatingProduct">
              <input
                id="changed.sku"
                v-model="product.sku"
                class="form-control"
                :class="{ 'is-invalid': validationErrorsUpdate['sku']}"
              />
              <div
                class="invalid-feedback"
                v-for="(error, index) in validationErrorsUpdate['sku']"
                :key="index"
              >{{ error }}</div>
            </td>
            <td v-else>{{ product.sku }}</td>

              <td v-if="index==updatingProduct">
                <input
                  id="changed.name"
                  v-model="product.name"
                  class="form-control"
                  :class="{ 'is-invalid': validationErrorsUpdate['name']}"
                />
                <div
                  class="invalid-feedback"
                  v-for="(error, index) in validationErrorsUpdate['name']"
                  :key="index"
                >{{ error }}</div>
              </td>
              <td v-else>{{ product.name }}</td>

          
                  <i class="fas fa-times p-0"></i>
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
```

La cuestión es que basicamente, a modo de prueba he tenido que dividir su código en 2...Uno para generar El encabezado y llenar la tabla (que se hace de forma correcta) y más abajo el modal para la edición.

```js
<form>
        <table class="table table-borderless rounded">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>SKU</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Origin Country</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Category</th>
              <th>Hs Code</th>
              <th>Width</th>
              <th>Height</th>
              <th>Length</th>
              <th>Weight</th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(product, index) in products" :key="index">
              <td>{{ product.sku }}</td>
              <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ product.origin_country }}</td>
              <td>{{ product.description }}</td>
              <td>{{ product.category }}</td>
              <td>{{ product.hs_code }}</td>
              <td>{{ product.width }}</td>
              <td>{{ product.height }}</td>
              <td>{{ product.length }}</td>
              <td>{{ product.weight }}</td>
              <td>
                <a
                  data-toggle="modal"
                  href= "#modalEdit"
                  class="btn btn-primary float-right ml-3"
                  v-on:click="setProduct(id)"
                >Modify</a>
              </td>
              <td>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="btn btn-link float-right"
                  v-on:click="removeProduct(index)"
                >
                  <i class="fas fa-times p-0"></i>
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
```

La cuestión es que mi modal no sirve, y ahora es un mutante, el cual muestro a continuación:

```js
<div class="modal fade" id="modalEdit">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-primary text-white">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalEditProductsTitle">Update your information</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>

            <div class="row justify-content-md-center modal-body">
              <div class="card bg-light border-white rounded py-4">
                <form v-for="(product, index) in products" :key="index">


                  <div class="row ml-5 mr-5" v-if="index==updatingProduct">
                     <div class="col p-0">
                      <div class="form-group" >
                        <label for sku>SKU</label>
                        <input id="changed.sku"  v-model="product.sku">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                   <div class="row ml-5 mr-5" v-if="index==updatingProduct">
                     <div class="col p-0">
                      <div class="form-group" >
                        <label for sku>Name</label>
                        <input id="changed.name" v-model="product.name">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="row mx-5 mt-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <button
                      type="submit"
                      class="mt-2 btn btn-success float-center"
                      v-on:click="createProduct()"
                    >Create Product</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Podrias añadir el codigo de javascript para poder ayudarte

Comment: @SaulEspinoza el código JS es el q va dentro del script... del resto es un archivo .vue que tiene toda la información HTML, Bootstrap y JS

Comment: Normalmente una vista o un componente de vue, deben de llevar un template, script y css, al parecer te falta codigo por mostrar en la parte donde vienen los methods, data etc

Comment: @SaulEspinoza Cómo hago para mostrarte todo el código? Por acá solo permite pocos caracteres... y mil gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: @SaulEspinoza Cómo se hace para que puedas ver todo el código? Por acá son muy pocos caracteres... Soy nuevo publicando... para estudiar, siempre veía lo q los otros respondían.